# Stop Button within a paper that has an onClick activating the onClick

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to stop the buttons activating the onClick? I've tried zIndexes, but they are not working.

```
 return (
    <div onClick={()=>history.push("/page")}>
      <main className={classes.layout}>

        <Paper className={classes.paperN}>


                <div>
                    <h1> Examples </h1>

                </div>
     

                <div className={classes.theButtons}>

                  <Button> When I'm clicked, the onclick to new page occurs </Button>

                </div>
           </div>
        </Paper>

      </main>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Does the button have a click handler on itself ? or what does that button do ?

Comment: They do, to download a PDF

Comment: Inside Paper  onclick handler call 

 `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

One is to stop the propagation and/or default action of the button.

something like

```
<Button onClick={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();}}> When I'm clicked, the onclick to new page occurs </Button>
```

the other is to detect if the click originated in a button and do nothing in your redirect handler.

```
<div
  onClick={(e) => {
    if (!e.target.closest("button")) {
      history.push("/page");
    }
  }}
>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The button onClick method worked for me! Really appreciate it :)